# CarouFredSel Window Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

Im very new to this (so you'll have to dumb it down for me) and i'm trying to understand how to make my CarouFredsel Slider shrink and stay proportional when the browser size is changed. The images cut off and move to the right, and sliders width changes, but not height. Thank for the help in advance.

Heres a link: https://brandon-mciver.squarespace.com
Here is all of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
$('#slider').carouFredSel({
    width: '100%',
    align: false,
    items: 3,
    items: {
        width: $('#wrapper').width() * 0.15,
        height: 400,
        visible: 1,
        minimum: 1
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        timeoutDuration : 6000,
        onBefore: function(data) {
            //  find current and next slide
            var currentSlide = $('.slide.active', this),
                nextSlide = data.items.visible,
                _width = $('#wrapper').width();

            //  resize currentslide to small version
            currentSlide.stop().animate({
                width: _width * 0.15
            });     
            currentSlide.removeClass( 'active' );

            //  hide current block
            data.items.old.add( data.items.visible ).find( '.slide-block'  ).stop().fadeOut();                  

            //  animate clicked slide to large size
            nextSlide.addClass( 'active' );
            nextSlide.stop().animate({
                width: _width * 0.7
            });                     
        },
        onAfter: function(data) {
            //  show active slide block
            data.items.visible.last().find( '.slide-block'     ).stop().fadeIn();
        }
    },
    onCreate: function(data){

        //  clone images for better sliding and insert them dynamacly in  slider
        var newitems = $('.slide',this).clone( true ),
            _width = $('#wrapper').width();

        $(this).trigger( 'insertItem', [newitems, newitems.length, false] );

        //  show images 
        $('.slide', this).fadeIn();
        $('.slide:first-child', this).addClass( 'active' );
        $('.slide', this).width( _width * 0.15 );

        //  enlarge first slide
        $('.slide:first-child', this).animate({
            width: _width * 0.7
        });

        //  show first title block and hide the rest
        $(this).find( '.slide-block' ).hide();
        $(this).find( '.slide.active .slide-block' ).stop().fadeIn();
    }
});

//  Handle click events
$('#slider').children().click(function() {
    $('#slider').trigger( 'slideTo', [this] );
});

  //    Enable code below if you want to support browser resizing
$(window).resize(function(){

    var slider = $('#slider'),
        _width = $('#wrapper').width();

    //  show images
    slider.find( '.slide' ).width( _width * 0.15 );

    //  enlarge first slide
    slider.find( '.slide.active' ).width( _width * 0.7 );

    //  update item width config
    slider.trigger( 'configuration', ['items.width', _width * 0.15] );
});

})
</script>


<style type="text/css" media="all">
html, body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
background: #f9f9f3;
}
body * {
font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #222;
line-height: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
padding-top: none;
border: 0px solid #fff;
background-color: #fff;
}
#slider {
margin: 75px 0 0 0;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(https://brandon-mciver.squarespace.com/s/ajax-loader.gif) center center     no-repeat;
}

#slider .slide {
position: relative;
display: none;
height: 400px;
float: left;
background-position: center right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
cursor: pointer;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

#slider .slide:first-child {
border: none;
}

#slider .slide.active {
cursor: default;
}

#slider .slide-block {
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
bottom: 75px;
display: inline-block;
width: 435px;
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);   
padding: 20px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #134B94;
border: 1px solid #fff;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider .slide-block h4 {
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
line-height: 1;
}
#slider .slide-block p {
margin: 0;
}

</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="slider">

    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://brandon-    mciver.squarespace.com/s/Rotator_TryChurch_3-1-a0wb.jpg);">
        <div class="slide-block">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://brandon-mciver.squarespace.com/s/Rotator_TryChurch_3-1-a0wb.jpg);">
        <div class="slide-block">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://brandon-mciver.squarespace.com/s/Rotator_TryChurch_3-1-a0wb.jpg);">
        <div class="slide-block">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```